# Rails: populate an existing table via a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

Say I have an existing migration in Rails:

```
class CreateStudies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :studies do |t|
      t.string :display_name, null: false
      t.string :tag_name, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :studies, :tag_name, unique: true
  end
end
```

Later on I realise that I would like to populate this table with a number of rows and I don't want to use `rake db:rollback` or the seeds.rb file. What is the format of the new migration file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just:

At the command prompt generate:

```
rails generate migration AddInitialStudies
```

And modify `up` and `down` method of generated migration:

```
class AddInitialStudies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Study.create(display_name: "Example name", tag_name: "example_name")
  end

  def down
    Study.delete_all
  end
end
```

At this point I generate one Study object, but you can add as many you want.

On `down`, remove records added on `up`, because rollback and migrate again will duplicate added records. I assume the only Study records are the created on `up`. Take care with `:tag_name`, which must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it's better to use **rake tasks** to generate some new objects rather than using migration. Here is a sample code https://github.com/maxmilan/Adverts_desk/blob/master/lib/tasks/advert_generators.rake#L3. You can also send number of generated objects as argument of task.